# Non alpha-numeric characters in URL

Tags: url, unicode, character-encoding, alphanumeric

If I visit http://†.com in Chrome or Internet Explorer, it will bring me to http://xn--lvg.com.

I know it doesn't work in Opera, Safari, and Firefox.

Why does † gets translated to `xn--lvg`? What's the relation between them? Is there a list that maps these weird characters to their translated equivalents in Chrome or Internet Explorer?

Comment: I just tested, an (at least in 5.1) it's working in Safari too :)!

Comment: It also works in firefox 6.0.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the [punycode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) representation.

Here is the [relevant RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3492).